# SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE error while accesing the url in browser

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, web-hosting, iis-8

Hi i am getting below error while trying to access the website which is hosted in IIS 8 for which the SSL certificate had got expired and i installed the new SSL certificate provided by GoDaddy, it was all working fine for 2 days and now it shows the below error. Let me know if anyone can figure out what is the issue

```
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SPT
{
    class Program
    {

            public static async Task RecognizeSpeechAsync()
        {
            // Creates an instance of a speech config with specified subscription key and service region.
            // Replace with your own subscription key // and service region (e.g., "westus").
            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(" 7cf359266c964dc789960abe063cc65b", "westus");

            // Creates a speech recognizer.
            using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Say something...");

                // Starts speech recognition, and returns after a single utterance is recognized. The end of a
                // single utterance is determined by listening for silence at the end or until a maximum of 15
                // seconds of audio is processed.  The task returns the recognition text as result. 
                // Note: Since RecognizeOnceAsync() returns only a single utterance, it is suitable only for single
                // shot recognition like command or query. 
                // For long-running multi-utterance recognition, use StartContinuousRecognitionAsync() instead.
                var result = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();

                // Checks result.
                if (result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"We recognized: {result.Text}");
                }
                else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
                }
                else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
                {
                    var cancellation = CancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");

                    if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails={cancellation.ErrorDetails}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static async Task SynthesisToSpeakerAsync()
        {
            // Creates an instance of a speech config with specified subscription key and service region.
            // Replace with your own subscription key and service region (e.g., "westus").
            // The default language is "en-us".
            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("7cf359266c964dc789960abe063cc65b", "westus");

            // Creates a speech synthesizer using speaker as audio output.
            using (var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config))
            {
                // Receive a text from console input and synthesize it to speaker.
                Console.WriteLine("Type some text that you want to speak...");
                Console.Write("> ");
                string text = Console.ReadLine();

                using (var result = await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text))
                {
                    if (result.Reason == ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Speech synthesized to speaker for text [{text}]");
                    }
                    else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
                    {
                        var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");

                        if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
                            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails=[{cancellation.ErrorDetails}]");
                            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
                        }
                    }
                }

                // This is to give some time for the speaker to finish playing back the audio
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        public static async Task SynthesisToVideoAsync()
        {
            var apiUrl = "https://api.videoindexer.ai";
            var accountId = "56fbb8f8-b9a8-4119-b46a-fa5fb6668ddd";
            var location = "westus2";
            var apiKey = "6f354f730bc141f9bc3e57e73c6001b0";

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            // create the http client
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            var client = new HttpClient(handler);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", apiKey);

            // obtain account access token
            var accountAccessTokenRequestResult = client.GetAsync($"{apiUrl}/auth/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/AccessToken?allowEdit=true").Result;
            var accountAccessToken = accountAccessTokenRequestResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Replace("\"", "");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key");

            // upload a video
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            Debug.WriteLine("Uploading...");
            // get the video from URL
            var videoUrl = "VIDEO_URL"; // replace with the video URL

            // as an alternative to specifying video URL, you can upload a file.
            // remove the videoUrl parameter from the query string below and add the following lines:
            //FileStream video =File.OpenRead(Globals.VIDEOFILE_PATH);
            //byte[] buffer =newbyte[video.Length];
            //video.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            //content.Add(newByteArrayContent(buffer));

            var uploadRequestResult = client.PostAsync($"{apiUrl}/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Videos?accessToken={accountAccessToken}&name=some_name&description=some_description&privacy=private&partition=some_partition&videoUrl={videoUrl}", content).Result;
            var uploadResult = uploadRequestResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            // get the video id from the upload result
            var videoId = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(uploadResult)["id"];
            Debug.WriteLine("Uploaded");
            Debug.WriteLine("Video ID: " + videoId);

            // obtain video access token            
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", apiKey);
            var videoTokenRequestResult = client.GetAsync($"{apiUrl}/auth/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Videos/{videoId}/AccessToken?allowEdit=true").Result;
            var videoAccessToken = videoTokenRequestResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Replace("\"", "");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key");

            // wait for the video index to finish
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);

                var videoGetIndexRequestResult = client.GetAsync($"{apiUrl}/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Videos/{videoId}/Index?accessToken={videoAccessToken}&language=English").Result;
                var videoGetIndexResult = videoGetIndexRequestResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                var processingState = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(videoGetIndexResult)["state"];

                Debug.WriteLine("");
                Debug.WriteLine("State:");
                Debug.WriteLine(processingState);

                // job is finished
                if (processingState != "Uploaded" && processingState != "Processing")
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("");
                    Debug.WriteLine("Full JSON:");
                    Debug.WriteLine(videoGetIndexResult);
                    break;
                }
            }

            // search for the video
            var searchRequestResult = client.GetAsync($"{apiUrl}/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Videos/Search?accessToken={accountAccessToken}&id={videoId}").Result;
            var searchResult = searchRequestResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Debug.WriteLine("");
            Debug.WriteLine("Search:");
            Debug.WriteLine(searchResult);

            // get insights widget url
            var insightsWidgetRequestResult = client.GetAsync($"{apiUrl}/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Videos/{videoId}/InsightsWidget?accessToken={videoAccessToken}&widgetType=Keywords&allowEdit=true").Result;
            var insightsWidgetLink = insightsWidgetRequestResult.Headers.Location;
            Debug.WriteLine("Insights Widget url:");
            Debug.WriteLine(insightsWidgetLink);

            // get player widget url
            var playerWidgetRequestResult = client.GetAsync($"{apiUrl}/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Videos/{videoId}/PlayerWidget?accessToken={videoAccessToken}").Result;
            var playerWidgetLink = playerWidgetRequestResult.Headers.Location;
            Debug.WriteLine("");
            Debug.WriteLine("Player Widget url:");
            Debug.WriteLine(playerWidgetLink);
        }


            static void Main()
        {
            RecognizeSpeechAsync().Wait();
            SynthesisToSpeakerAsync().Wait();
            SynthesisToVideoAsync().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Please press a key to continue.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why does my secure ssl page give Error code: sec\_error\_revoked\_certificate even though certificate is current and all links/stylesheets/etc are secure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375935/why-does-my-secure-ssl-page-give-error-code-sec-error-revoked-certificate-even)

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375935/why-does-my-secure-ssl-page-give-error-code-sec-error-revoked-certificate-even#12376621

Comment: Use Jexus Manager https://jexusmanager.com to run SSL Diagnostics.